# Why is it possible to click the award bounty button when you can't award the bonus yet?

Tags: bug

At the moment, after I raise a bounty, I experience the following two problems:

1) I can't tell (on that page) that I can't award it yet, and how long until I'm allowed to award the bounty:

[image]

2) I can try to award the bounty, and have to go through an "Are you sure" dialog, only to be told that I can't.

[image]

How about disabling that button and popping up "You have 9 hours to go" in the mouse over?

Comment: I think the site wide general UX pattern is that no buttons are disabled if you can't do an action yet and on clicking it shows the server side error. If this UX pattern is changed here, it should change everywhere.

Comment: If it was something that could be done incrementally, then starting with buttons that take you through a confirmation dialog before returning the server error would be the place to start.

Comment: Even if the UX pattern is that no buttons are disabled, asking *"Are you sure?"* just to throw a *"Haha, you can't!"* in the user's face is a bad UX.

Comment: My issue is at a tangent to this bounty question _ I've just been informed by SO that I've earned the "set bounties" privilege (75 reputation) _ But I've only just reached 60 reputation and all viewpoints of my account_ including **Help Center > Privileges > Set bounties** page are all showing only 60 points _ My conclusion was there must be a bug_ which is why I visited this question

Comment: BTW: If your intent is to reward one of the existing answers, then it's usually more beneficial to that answer to leave the bounty active for the entire available time. The primary effect of an open bounty is that the question gets significantly more exposure. This exposure, in my experience, will result in all of the good answers on the question getting additional upvotes. Ending the bounty early will probably result in the answer getting fewer upvotes than it would have if the bounty is left on the question. It's probably a good idea to state to which answer you plan to give the bounty.

Comment: For the one 50 rep bounty I tracked, the bounty was explicitly stated to be going to Answer #3 and was left on the question for the entire bounty period (bounty was manually awarded within the 24 hours after the end of the bounty). The score changes were: question up 10, answer #1 up 16, answer #2 up 2, answer #3 up 7, answer #4 up 2, answer #5 up 3.

Comment: What @Makyen said two comments above is correct. In fact, that happens even with regular questions: if OP waits some time before accepting an answer it can get some more upvotes. However (at least in the small tag I'm active), if OP immediately accepts an answer after it's posted the upvotes disappear. That being said, if you have just one answer (or if the answer you prefer is the most upvoted one), just leave the system to reward the bounty automatically.

Comment: @maik since you had 15 rep differences probably it was caused by accept-unaccept within minutes.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado yeah, I agree it's super annoying. I tried to give a bounty once and I basically I resorted to coming back every few hours and clicking the "give bounty" button until it worked.

Comment: Same reason you can click on the upvote button of one of your own posts and a pop-up then says "You can't vote for your own post"

Comment: I think the disabling solution makes the user though he/she doesn't have the right to do that. And may be no one though there is a tooltip(why ever you point to a disabled button!?) The current method is good, but it can be better with just avoide to display confirmation and just display informatic message(if there isn't time for bounty yet).

Comment: Thanks for reply @Shinjo _ appreciated _ There's a new (& clickable) bounty section now on my main SO account wall _ I'm assuming its appearance is due much like when a badge is awarded = non-retractable _ Thanks again

Comment: Bohemian confessing to upvoting his own posts there, wondered where all that rep came from, must have been before they stopped it working :D ;) ...

Comment: @Bohemian what you said made me remember of an unrelated issue: some time ago I turned an answer of mine into a community wiki. Then, just as a curiosity, I clicked "upvote" to see what would happen, and I got the expected *""You can't vote for your own post"*. However, it makes no sense, because a wiki is not *my post*, even if I created it! I should be able to upvote a wiki, even one I created myself, after it's detached from my RP as an user. I thought about asking this here on meta but I gave up because I can foresee everyone would disagree with me.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I guess I know what [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56599663/4235784) you are talking about... I remember trying the same thing on my own community wiki answer to that post ;) Although our names are still visible on the posts I agree that this just misses the point of not being able to votes on one's own answer as there is no rep gain from it.