# I accidentally forgot to change from the default bounty reason. What do I do?

Tags: support, bounty

I put a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56154380/how-does-this-piece-of-code-determine-array-size-without-using-sizeof) giving credit to @JohnBode for the amazing work he did on [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56156165). However, I made a mistake and forgot to change the bounty reason from "Draw attention" to "Reward existing answer" and I don't see an option to change it.

What do I do? Can anyone help me?

Comment: flag the question for moderator attention, and describe the issue

Comment: We wouldn’t do anything about this if it was flagged. All that the “reason” option does is change the banner text a little. We can only remove the bounty at which point you may have to set a higher bounty if you wanted to place a new one (not 100% certain on that).

Comment: Besides, your custom text content makes it clear you are doing this because there is an amazing answer. It’s clear enough what the bounty is there for. The fact that you picked the wrong option doesn’t alter how you can reward it; you still get to pick that answer once the minimal waiting time is over.

Comment: BTW: I suggest waiting to award the bounty until the end of the 7 day bounty period. Basically, leaving it on longer is likely to give the user you are awarding the bounty to even more points through upvotes. Please see [this comment of mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386685/why-is-it-possible-to-click-the-award-bounty-button-when-you-cant-award-the-bon#comment708607_386685) and the next comment there for more detail.

Comment: @Makyen I know.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You don’t need to do anything.

All that the bounty reason options do is determine what text is used in the bounty post notice. That’s all. Your custom bounty notice text makes it perfectly clear what the bounty is for here.

Once the minimal waiting time is over, you are free to award the bounty to any answer you see fit. At most, add a comment under the question to explain your “mistake” here if you worry about it.

Moderators can only remove the bounty at this point. While you can then re-do your bounty, I’m not 100% certain you would be allowed to set it at 100 again or if you’d be required to double the amount. Probably not worth the risk here, eh?

Comment: That text might be important to people browsing the featured questions hoping to find something to answer. It's entirely conceivable someone won't read the following line indicating that it's to reward an existing answer.

Comment: @jpmc26: sure, but that's a *small* risk. We have plenty of people ignoring the 'award an existing answer' banner entirely and posting new (often low quality) answers anyway.

Comment: @jpmc26: and the text isn't even shown anywhere but on the question page itself...

Comment: @MartijnPieters And in the edit history...

Comment: @MartijnPieters, if moderators can remove the bounty, is the rep spent on the bounty paid back, or does it get lost?

Comment: @ilkkachu: when a moderator removes a bounty, the rep goes back to the person that set the bounty.  **We don't usually do this unless there are very specific extenuating circumstances**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Like what?